# Columns not getting aligning correctly on the screen using bootsrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am implementing a UI for angular 7 application using bootstrap. The UI form contains four elements per row. You have label and input control on the left and similar on the right. So I tried setting col-md-2 for both the labels and col-md-3 for both the forms. When I do that there is space on the right and presume thats because the total amounts to 10 columns. If I increase the input of both the left and right side by 1 that is col-md-4 , the rightmost control touches the border. I need the left and right to be equal with little margin on the left and right side of the border.

I have managed to create a stackblitz to replicate the issue. Have also solved the right spacing issue. You can see the style is commented on stackblitz. How do i create spacing between the control as at the moment it is too cluttered. Also I want to make it looked stacked on small screen. Please see the updated screenshot below  for reference. Its labeled Updated output

stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uypvsy

Here are the screenshots

with col-md-3

[image]

With cold-md-4 just applied to the first row

[image]

Html code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header panel-heading">
    <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Details</span>
    <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
      <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div *ngIf="FundDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

      <div class="form-group row">

        <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-sm-11 col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-11 ">
          <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FundName}}</div>
          <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FundName" />
        </div>

        <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Investment Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-11">
          <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.InvestmentStatusName}}</div>
          <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatusId" [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Make Anonymous</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-11">
          <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</div>
          <label *ngIf="EditMode"> <input type="checkbox" [checked]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                value="{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous}}" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</label>
        </div>


        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Flagship</label>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-11">
          <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FlagShipFundName}}</div>
          <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FlagShipFundId" [data]="FundDetails.FlagshipFunds" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
        </div>

      </div>

      Updated html based on suggestion

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header panel-heading">
          <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Details</span>
          <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div *ngIf="FundDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

            <div class="form-row">

              <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FundName}}</div>
                <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FundName" />
              </div>

              <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Investment Status</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.InvestmentStatusName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatusId" [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Make Anonymous</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</div>
                <label *ngIf="EditMode"> <input type="checkbox" [checked]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                value="{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous}}" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</label>
              </div>


              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Flagship</label>

              <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FlagShipFundName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FlagShipFundId" [data]="FundDetails.FlagshipFunds" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row">

              <!-- <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{formatInceptionDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="getInceptionDate">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div> -->

              <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.InceptionDate}}</div>
                <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [format]="'dd-MMM-yyyy'" [value]="getInceptionDate" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InceptionDate" (valueChange)="inceptionDateChanged($event)">
                </kendo-datepicker>
              </div>


              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Account Mandate</label>
              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.AccountMandateName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.AccountMandateId" [data]="FundDetails.AccountMandates" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-row">
              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Vehicle Type</label>
              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.VehicleTypeName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.VehicleTypeId" [data]="FundDetails.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" (valueChange)="vehicleTypeChanged($event)">
                  valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>



              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Bloomberg Ticker</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.BloombergTicker}}</div>
                <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.BloombergTicker" />
              </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-row">

              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Primary Class</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.PrimaryClassDescripton}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.PrimaryClassId" [data]="FundDetails.PrimaryClasses" [filterable]="false" textField="DESCRIPTION" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>



            </div>




            <div class="form-row">

              <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 30px;">
                <div class="desc-header">Details</div>
                <div class="divEditor">
                  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [id]="'ckDetails'" *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 11px;" debounce="500" [config]="EditorConfig" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.AccountMandateCustomisation">
                  </ckeditor>
                  <div style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode" [innerHTML]="FundDetails.AccountMandateCustomisation">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>





          </div>
          <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
            <!-- <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                        View Fund Snapshot
                    </button>
                </span> -->

            <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="updateFund()">Save</button>
    
                </span>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="cancelFund">Cancel</button>
                </span>
            <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                        (click)="deleteFund()">Delete</button>
                </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header panel-heading">
          <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Details</span>
          <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div *ngIf="FundDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

            <div class="form-group row">

              <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-sm-11 col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-11 ">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FundName}}</div>
                <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FundName" />
              </div>

              <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Investment Status</label>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-11">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.InvestmentStatusName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatusId" [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Make Anonymous</label>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-11">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</div>
                <label *ngIf="EditMode"> <input type="checkbox" [checked]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                value="{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous}}" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</label>
              </div>


              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-sm-11 col-form-label header">Flagship</label>

              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-11">
                <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FlagShipFundName}}</div>
                <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FlagShipFundId" [data]="FundDetails.FlagshipFunds" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
              </div>

            </div>

            Updated html based on suggestion

            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header panel-heading">
                <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Details</span>
                <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div *ngIf="FundDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

                  <div class="form-row">

                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FundName}}</div>
                      <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FundName" />
                    </div>

                    <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Investment Status</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.InvestmentStatusName}}</div>
                      <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatusId" [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                      </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Make Anonymous</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</div>
                      <label *ngIf="EditMode"> <input type="checkbox" [checked]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                value="{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous}}" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.IsAnonymous"
                                style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{FundDetails.IsAnonymous ? "Yes" : "No"}}</label>
                    </div>


                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Flagship</label>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.FlagShipFundName}}</div>
                      <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.FlagShipFundId" [data]="FundDetails.FlagshipFunds" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                      </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-row">

                    <!-- <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{formatInceptionDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="getInceptionDate">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div> -->

                    <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.InceptionDate}}</div>
                      <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [format]="'dd-MMM-yyyy'" [value]="getInceptionDate" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InceptionDate" (valueChange)="inceptionDateChanged($event)">
                      </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div>


                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Account Mandate</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.AccountMandateName}}</div>
                      <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.AccountMandateId" [data]="FundDetails.AccountMandates" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                      </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>

                  </div>


                  <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Vehicle Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.VehicleTypeName}}</div>
                      <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.VehicleTypeId" [data]="FundDetails.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" (valueChange)="vehicleTypeChanged($event)">
                        valueField="ID">
                      </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>



                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Bloomberg Ticker</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.BloombergTicker}}</div>
                      <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.BloombergTicker" />
                    </div>

                  </div>


                  <div class="form-row">

                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Primary Class</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.PrimaryClassDescripton}}</div>
                      <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.PrimaryClassId" [data]="FundDetails.PrimaryClasses" [filterable]="false" textField="DESCRIPTION" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                      </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>



                  </div>




                  <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 30px;">
                      <div class="desc-header">Details</div>
                      <div class="divEditor">
                        <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [id]="'ckDetails'" *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 11px;" debounce="500" [config]="EditorConfig" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.AccountMandateCustomisation">
                        </ckeditor>
                        <div style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode" [innerHTML]="FundDetails.AccountMandateCustomisation">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>





                </div>
                <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
                  <!-- <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                        View Fund Snapshot
                    </button>
                </span> -->

                  <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="updateFund()">Save</button>
    
                </span>
                  <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="cancelFund">Cancel</button>
                </span>
                  <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                        (click)="deleteFund()">Delete</button>
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Updated output based on suggestion on big screen

[image]

Updated output based on suggestion on small screen

[image]

Comment: Your CSS code could be critical in providing a solution for you. Please include it in your question. (thx)

Comment: I would always suggest that you start to develop from the small screen and then continue to a bigger screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just deleting or commenting on the **header** class improves considerably in mobile view:
[image]

On the other hand, there are div like `<div *ngIf ="IsVehicleDependent">` that behave like a column even if they do not have the class `col-sm -...`. I am learning ReactJS and for these cases there is `<React.Fragment>`. I looked for something similar for Angular and I found `<ng-container>`. I applied it and improved the desktop view.

[image]

Comment: Your comments have been really usefull. Could you tell me how to improve the spacing between the controls. At the moment they are sticking to each other. Top to the bottom as well as sideways.

Comment: There should be space between Name , Make Anonymous, VehicleType etc and also some spacing between Name input control and Investment Status label

Comment: Replacing ``<div class = "form-row">`` with ``<div class = "form-group row">`` and adding CSS styles ``.card-body label {text-align: right}`` can be improved.

Comment: I initially had form-group row and changed it to form-row as per your earlier suggestion

Comment: Do you think the size of the label and dropdown list should be uniform

Comment: I do not know, more than the size, aligning the labels on the right would help. I also think that **Make Anonymous** breaks the symmetry. I would give a better location to that checkbox.

Comment: I just felt that the height of the dropdown and input controls if made uniform may look nice . Yes the checkbox breaks the symmerty

Answer (score 0):

Without doing the test with the angle itself, and looking at the code, I would change **"form-group row"** to **"form-row"**. It would also eliminate **"col-sm-11"**. And additionally, close at least 3 div ().
The structure should be more like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        Fund Details
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngIf="FundDetails">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Label 1</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Input 1">
                </div>
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Label 2</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Input 2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Label 3</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Input 3">
                </div>
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Label 4</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Input 4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand, will two DIV with "card-body" class be necessary?

Comment: I have tried to incorporate post of your suggestions. I have updated the post with the new html and how the output looks like on big and small screen. If you see i still have the problem of input controls stretching to the border. Also there are no padding or spaces in between controls. I guess that is after removal of form-group row

Comment: mmm, the HTML code looks more complicated. According to the last html that you updated, I see many nested `cards`. For these cases it is better to build with test data and once the design behaves correctly, replace with Angular.

Comment: I have managed to create a stackbliz. Managed to resolve the space on the right. I have commented out the style. You can see it on stackblitz. But how am I going to have spacing in between the controls. Ever since i have changed it to form-row. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uypvsy

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a responsive CSS rule to `.header` elements. I see they are set to `width: 8%;` currently which looks fine when the layout is wide but goes squirrelly at narrow width. Change width to 100% and it actually looks fine. Something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 'YOUR_BREAKPOINT_WIDTH_HERE') {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```